# PagerSlidingTabStrip- how to right to left tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabcontainer

I am using **PagerSlidingTabStrip** library to make my tabs . 
I can't swap it right to left.

I've searched and the solution was to

```
add tabsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

but it didn't work for me .

I changed the library code to this but it didn't work :

```
tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    tabsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    addView(tabsContainer);
```

How can I right to left the tabs?

Comment: Do you mean the order in which the tabs appear? Do you mean the direction the text captions within the tabs flows? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean , How can I make tabs appear from right to left instead of from left to right?

Comment: You would need to reverse the order of your tab creation.

Answer (score 1):

if you use this library

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

add this line in PagerSlidingTabStrip before line 164 :

```
pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getAdapter().getCount()-1);
```

like this :

```
public void setViewPager(ViewPager pager) {
    this.pager = pager;

    if (pager.getAdapter() == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
    }

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getAdapter().getCount()-1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in your activity reverse fragment sort position like this:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
            "Top New Free", "Trending" };

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    boolean enableStickerToSticker = true;
    boolean enableCommentSticker = true;
    boolean enableLatestTap = true;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return LatestListFragment.newInstance(TITLES.length - 1
                    - position);
    }

}
```

but if you use this library :

https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

change this line in activity :

```
   pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

to this:

```
   pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getAdapter().getCount()-1);
```

and reverse fragment index in adapter like this :

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(TITLES.length-1-position);
    }
```

Comment: This solution works fine when tabs size exceed the screen. If there is few tabs, the tab layout does not attach to right side of screen however tabs ordination will be true.

Answer (score 0):

add: `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to  PagerSlidingTabStrip layout